# QGraphicsScene size increases too much when an item is dragged to its left border

Tags: qt, pyqt, hotkeys, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsScene with a few movable items on it. When I drag an item to scene border, the size of the scene increases (it's okay, it should increase), and the scroll bars appear (that's okay too).

But even if the moving item exceeds window borders a few pixels, scene size increases about twice at once, in one big leap.

Here's a small demo (pardon my PyQt):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsRectItem

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #########################################
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
    ##########################################



    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    view.setMouseTracking(True)
    view.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

    rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem(-50, -50, 100, 100)
    rect_item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    scene.addItem(rect_item)


    rect_item2 = QGraphicsRectItem(-50, -50, 100, 100)
    rect_item2.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    scene.addItem(rect_item2)

    rect_item2.setPos(-120, -120)

    view.setScene(scene)
    view.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You should drag the squares to left border, and the size will increase twice at one moment when the item reaches window border.

Cannot you tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is for performance, to prevent a rapid series of many consecutive events resizing the scene rect every time an item is moved past the scene's borders. However if you want that to happen, you will need to re-implement the QGraphicsItem's mouse even handler mouseMoveEvent to behave as you wish instead of the default behaviour provided. That will need to include updating the sceneRect the way to prefer.

Comment: Well, but why it behaves normally when I move the graphics item right or down?